# Unity5.3 MiniJson Derserialize Multi Tier Json

Tags: c#, json, list, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to Deserialize my Json file into its various components.

The Json file that i have created look like this

```
{  
  "Restaurants":[  
    {  
        "Name":"test",
        "Id":0,
        "PlateSet":[  
            {  
                "Title":"Plate1",
                "Color":{  
                    "r":229,
                    "g":0,
                    "b":20,
                    "a":255
                },
                "Price":12
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have managed to get the Name,ID,Title and Price out. but i cannot seem to get the Color out for some reason. I suspect its because whatever i am doing is ment for Arrays and the Color is not an Array.

here is my Code.

```
public void DictionaryAdd()
{
    var dict1 = MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(rJsonData.ToString()) as Dictionary<string, object>;

    var list1 = dict1["Restaurants"] as List<object>;
    Dictionary<string, object> dict2 = list1[0] as Dictionary<string, object>;
    var list2 = dict2["PlateSet"] as List<object>;
    Dictionary<string, object> dict3 = list2[0] as Dictionary<string, object>;
    var list3 = dict3["Color"] as List<object>;

    //var list3 = dict3["Color"] as List<object>;
    //Dictionary<string, int> dict4 = list3[0] as Dictionary<string, int>;

    Debug.Log(dict2["Name"]);
    Debug.Log(dict3["Title"]);
    Debug.Log(dict3["Price"]);
    Debug.Log(dict3["Color"]);
    Debug.Log("D1 " + dict1.Count);
    Debug.Log("L1 " + list1.Count);
    Debug.Log("D2 " + dict2.Count);
    Debug.Log("L2 " + list2.Count);
    Debug.Log("D3 " + dict3.Count);
    Debug.Log("L3 " + list3.Count);

    //Debug.Log(list3.Count);
}
```

Any help on how i should go about this? 
also maybe if i could convert the color back to a color at this point that would be super if you know how?

also im pretty newish to C# so if you have a suggestion on how i could do this better? I'm all ears :)

Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have multiple `Json` questions. Here is a secret.

**TEESTING YOUR OWN JSON MADE EASY**.

1.Copy your Json file and paste it [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html#ad-output). Click **Escape** button.

2.Create a test `string` and paste the converted info there(IDE/Mono/VS).
With the Json in your question I got:

```
string test = "{  \r\n  \"Restaurants\":[  \r\n    {  \r\n        \"Name\":\"test\",\r\n        \"Id\":0,\r\n        \"PlateSet\":[  \r\n            {  \r\n                \"Title\":\"Plate1\",\r\n                \"Color\":{  \r\n                    \"r\":229,\r\n                    \"g\":0,\r\n                    \"b\":20,\r\n                    \"a\":255\r\n                },\r\n                \"Price\":12\r\n            }\r\n        ]\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}";
```

3.Copy your original `Json` file again from your question. Go [here](http://json2csharp.com/) and past it.Click the **Generate** Button.

4.Copy the output classes from that website and put them in your IDE. Now remove all the `{ get; set; }` from each variable in each class and put semicolon after each one. You **MUST** remove them.

5.Put `[Serializable]` on top of each class that you received from that website.

6.Done. Now you can use

```
 BaseRestaurant restaurant = new BaseRestaurant();
 restaurant = JsonUtility.FromJson<BaseRestaurant>(test);
```

to convert your string to class. This will be useful for anyone having problems with Json. Since your Json is class array inside another class array, you need nested for loop to easily get all the information from the `Json`. Tested with **Unity 5.4.0.13B**. Any class it generates that says `RootObject` is the **only** class you should reference in your main code. I had to rename the class to `BaseRestaurant` to make more sense.

Below is the final result:

```
[Serializable]
public class Color
{
    public int r;
    public int g;
    public int b;
    public int a;
}

[Serializable]
public class PlateSet
{
    public string Title;
    public Color Color;
    public int Price;
}

[Serializable]
public class Restaurant
{
    public string Name;
    public int Id;
    public List<PlateSet> PlateSet;
}

[Serializable]
public class BaseRestaurant
{
    public List<Restaurant> Restaurants;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
void Start()
{
    BaseRestaurant restaurant = new BaseRestaurant();
    string test = "{  \r\n  \"Restaurants\":[  \r\n    {  \r\n        \"Name\":\"test\",\r\n        \"Id\":0,\r\n        \"PlateSet\":[  \r\n            {  \r\n                \"Title\":\"Plate1\",\r\n                \"Color\":{  \r\n                    \"r\":229,\r\n                    \"g\":0,\r\n                    \"b\":20,\r\n                    \"a\":255\r\n                },\r\n                \"Price\":12\r\n            }\r\n        ]\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}";

restaurant = JsonUtility.FromJson<BaseRestaurant>(test);
if (restaurant == null)
{
    Debug.Log("Null");
    return;
}

for (int i = 0; i < restaurant.Restaurants.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.Log("Name: " + restaurant.Restaurants[i].Name);
    Debug.Log("ID: " + restaurant.Restaurants[i].Id);
    Debug.Log("PlateSet: " + restaurant.Restaurants[i].PlateSet);

    for (int j = 0; j < restaurant.Restaurants[i].PlateSet.Count; j++)
    {
        Debug.Log("Title: " + restaurant.Restaurants[i].PlateSet[j].Title);

        Debug.Log("Color r: " + restaurant.Restaurants[i].PlateSet[j].Color.r);
        Debug.Log("Color g: " + restaurant.Restaurants[i].PlateSet[j].Color.g);
        Debug.Log("Color b: " + restaurant.Restaurants[i].PlateSet[j].Color.b);
        Debug.Log("Color a: " + restaurant.Restaurants[i].PlateSet[j].Color.a);

        Debug.Log("Color r: " + restaurant.Restaurants[i].PlateSet[j].Price);
    }
  }
}
```

This took about 3 minutes to do.